# Using additional classes in AXIS WebService

Tags: java, web-services, axis

Let's say I have simple working WebService on AXIS. I want to instantiate external class in it. The class needs to use WebService class static fields so I put it in the same JWS file like this:

```
public class RunTaskServer {

    static int count;

    public int task()
    {
        Structure s = new Structure();
    }
}

class Structure {
    public Structure() {
        RunTaskServer server = new RunTaskServer();
        server.count++;
    }
}
```

After invoking "task" method from Java client it throws java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException in client but when I comment out

```
Structure s = new Structure();
```

everything works well. Can you tell me how to get rid of this exception?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure why you are trying to do what you are doing. However that class you have created is a non-scoped class within the main. Not only that, but your main method has to return an int, but you are returning nothing. Try something like this (if this doesn't work, then please supply more info)

```
public class RunTaskServer {

    static int count;

    public int task()
    {
       Structure s = new Structure();
       return count;
    }

    private class Structure {
        public Structure() {
           RunTaskServer server = new RunTaskServer();
           server.count++;
        }
    }
}
```

And thats before I study the code and realise that what you are doing is circular